# ¿Cómo asigno aleatoriamente las alergias del arreglo alergias al arreglo alergiaPaciente?

Tags: c

El arreglo alergias es:

```
char alergias[12][30] = {"antibiótico", "polvo", "cítricos", "mariscos", "chocolate", "semillas"};
```

Lo que quiero hacer es asignar aleatoriamente una de estas alergias al arreglo alergiaPaciente que se encuentra dentro de la estructura DatosMedicos:

```
typedef struct DatosMedicos{

   float peso;
   float estatura;
   char *alergiaPaciente;
}DatosMedicos;
```

Esta operación la tengo que hacer dentro de la función capturaPaciente(). Me ayudarían mucho si sólo me dijeran cómo puedo hacer la asignación, es decir tomar una cadena del arreglo alergias y ponerla en el arreglo alergiaPaciente.

```
Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente *paciente){

    char alergias[12][30] = {"antibiótico", "polvo", "cítricos", "mariscos", "chocolate", "semillas"};

    printf("Nombre del paciente:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->nombre);
    printf("Sexo:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->sexo);
    printf("Teléfono:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->telefono);
    printf("Edad:");
    scanf("%i", &paciente->edad);
    printf("Peso:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.peso);
    printf("estatura:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.estatura);


    return paciente;

}
```

El programa captura los datos de un paciente y los muestra, lo único que falta por hacer es asignar aleatoriamente las alergias. Este es el programa completo:

```
#define MAXCHAR 40
#define MAXTEL 14
#define MAXCITAS 30

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct DatosMedicos{

   float peso;
   float estatura;
   char *alergiaPaciente;
}DatosMedicos;

typedef struct Paciente{

    char *nombre;
    int edad;
    char *sexo;
    char *telefono;
    DatosMedicos datosmedicos;

}Paciente;

typedef struct cola{

    int inicio;
    int final;
    Paciente *citas;
    
}queue;

Paciente *creaPaciente(void);
Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente *);
void listarPaciente(Paciente );

int main(){

    Paciente *paciente;

    paciente = creaPaciente();
    capturaPaciente(paciente);
    listarPaciente(*paciente);

    free(paciente);

    return 0;
}

Paciente *creaPaciente(){

    Paciente *paciente = (Paciente*)malloc(sizeof(Paciente));
    paciente->nombre = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
    paciente->telefono = (char*)malloc(MAXTEL*sizeof(char));
    paciente->sexo = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));
    paciente->datosmedicos->alergia = (char*)malloc(MAXCHAR*sizeof(char));

    return paciente;
}
    
Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente *paciente){

    char alergias[12][30] = {"antibiótico", "polvo", "cítricos", "mariscos", "chocolate", "semillas"};

    printf("Nombre del paciente:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->nombre);
    printf("Sexo:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->sexo);
    printf("Teléfono:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->telefono);
    printf("Edad:");
    scanf("%i", &paciente->edad);
    printf("Peso:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.peso);
    printf("estatura:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.estatura);


    return paciente;

}

void listarPaciente(Paciente paciente){

    printf("Nombre: %s\n", paciente.nombre);
    printf("Edad: %d\n", paciente.edad);
    printf("Sexo: %s\n", paciente.sexo);
    printf("Teléfono: %s\n", paciente.telefono);
    printf("Peso: %f\n", paciente.datosmedicos.peso);
    printf("Estatura: %f\n", paciente.datosmedicos.estatura);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo asigno aleatoriamente las alergias del arreglo alergias al arreglo alergiaPaciente?

Primero que nada, `alergiaPaciente` no es un arreglo, sino, un puntero a `char` (son dos cosas diferentes). Para seleccionar de forma aleatoria debes usar la función [rand](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/).

En este caso, debemos escoger un índice aleatorio que va entre `0` a `11`:

```c
int indice = rand() % 12;
```

Entonces, el algoritmo debe quedar así:

- Seleccionamos un índice de forma aleatoria.
- Obtenemos la longitud de la cadena que seleccionamos de forma aleatoria.
- Reservamos memoria con la función [malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) para crear un array de `N` elementos (+ el caracter nulo).
- Copiamos el contenido de la cadena seleccionada en el nuevo array reservado (esto se lo hace con la función [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)).

En código C quedaría así:

```c
char alergias[12][30] = {"antibiótico", "polvo", "cítricos", "mariscos", "chocolate", "semillas"};
int indice = rand() % 12;
int len = strlen(alergias[indice]);
paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente, alergias[indice]);
```

Sin embargo, esta solución no es tan eficiente (en cuestión de velocidad), puesto en cada llamada debe reservar memoria y luego hacer una copia.

Como verás, el array `alergias` tiene una [duración de almacenamiento automático](https://riptutorial.com/es/c/topic/3597/clases-de-almacenamiento), es decir, se crea cuando la función inicia y se libera cuando termina. Entonces, haremos que `alergias` termine con una [duración de almacenamiento estático](https://riptutorial.com/es/c/topic/3597/clases-de-almacenamiento) (se mantienen activas durante toda la ejecución del programa):

```c
Paciente *capturaPaciente(Paciente *paciente)
{
    static char alergias[][30] = {"antibiótico", "polvo", "cítricos", "mariscos", "chocolate", "semillas"};
    paciente->datosmedicos.alergiaPaciente = alergias[rand() % 12];
    
    printf("Nombre del paciente:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->nombre);
    printf("Sexo:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->sexo);
    printf("Teléfono:");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", paciente->telefono);
    printf("Edad:");
    scanf("%i", &paciente->edad);
    printf("Peso:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.peso);
    printf("estatura:");
    scanf("%f", &paciente->datosmedicos.estatura);
    return paciente;
}
```

De esta manera, lo único que debemos hacer es copiar la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array en el puntero `alergiaPaciente`. Con esto evitas llamar a `malloc` y hacer una copia y sabes, esta solución me parece más simple, puesto no necesitas liberar la memoria manualmente y de paso, es menos propenso a que ocurra una [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria).